# Поведение std::function зависит от компилятора

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A{
    static inline std::function<void()> func;
    static inline int value;

    static bool set(std::function<void()> func_, int value_){
        func = func_;
        value = value_;

        return static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func);
    }

    static void call(){
        std::cout << value << " : " << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func) << std::endl;
        func();
    }
};

struct B{
    static void func(){
    }

    static inline bool res = A<int>::set(B::func, 42);// || static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func);
};

int main(){
    A<int>::call();
    return 0;
}
```

для gcc (начиная с 7 и до последнего) в результате получается вывод

```
42 : false

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
```

т.е. объект в переменной func пустой

если раскомментировать вторую часть строки

```
static inline bool res = A<int>::set(B::func, 42) || static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func);
```

то вывод становится тем, который нужен (при этом раскоментированная часть даже не вызывается)

```
42 : true

0
```

при этом в clang любой версии все нормально и с закоментированным куском.

Что не так с кодом или с gcc?

---

Спасибо HolyBlackCat

Перемещение static func переменной в функцию отлично помогло. Код ниже работает как ожидалось

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A{
    static std::function<void()>& func(){
        static std::function<void()> func;
        return func;
    }
    // static inline std::function<void()> func;

    static bool set(std::function<void()> func_){
        func() = func_;
        return static_cast<bool>(func());
    }

    static void call(){
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func()) << std::endl;
        func()();
    }
};

struct B{
    static void func(){
        std::cout << "func" << std::endl;
    }

    static inline bool res = A<int>::set(B::func);// || static_cast<bool>(A<int>::func);
};

int main(){
    A<int>::call();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Навскидку: здесь банальное «фиаско инициализации», т.е. `res` инициализируется раньше, чем `func` & `value`. Т.е. последующая инициализация вышеозначенных переменных просто затирает то, что выставила инициализация `res`.

Comment: Очевидно, что не стоит полагаться на порядок динамической инициализации.

Comment: на счет порядка динамической инициализации не понял совсем. а инициализация res до инициализации func и value как повлияет на установку func в методе set?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что сначала инициализируется res вместе с вызовом A<int>::set и A::func устанавливается в правильное значение. А потом A::func инициализируется еще раз "само по себе" и становится пустым?

Comment: Видимо да. Но неопределенное поведение вы получаете уже на `func = func_;`, потому что `func` не инициализирована.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Что не так с кодом или с gcc?

В комментариях правильно пишут, дело в порядке инициализации.

В обоих случаях правильная работа не гарантируется.

Судя по [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization), инициализация статических переменных в шаблонах классов (когда переменные не были явно специализированы) выполняется в произвольном порядке, в том числе относительно всей остальной ([неконстантной](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization)) инциализации глобальных/статических переменных.

Так что компилятор вполне может инициализировать `B::res` до `A<int>::func`, что GCC и делает в первом случае.

То, что GCC меняет порядок инициализации, когда понимает, что `B::res` зависит от `A<int>::func` (второй случай) - не более, чем любезность разработчиков GCC.

Если `B::res` инициализируется до `A<int>::func`, то это приводит к использованию `func` до его инициализации и неопределенному поведению.

---

Чтобы не отстреливать себе постоянно ногу порядком инициализации, можно помещать чувствительные к порядку инициализации переменные в функции:

В `class A`:

```
static std::function<void()> &func()
{
    static std::function<void()> ret;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: На самом деле создание локальных статических переменных вовсе не гарантирует отсутствие проблем с порядком инициализации. Зато (при наличии динамической инициализации) гарантирует оверхед при создании этой переменной и при каждом обращении к этой функции.

Comment: @VTT *"не гарантирует отсутствие проблем"* Именно в этом случае, или вообще? Понятно, что это не спасает от 100% проблем с порядком инициализации, но в этом случае помогает. На счет оверхеда: [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23829671/2752075), что он якобы совсем небольшой. Да и непонятно, что можно использовать вместо этого подхода (разве что действительно писать классы так, чтобы им был безразличен порядок динамической инициализации).

Comment: Вообще. Вместо этого подхода можно использовать явную инициализацию (и явную деинициализацию кстати тоже).